# jdbc check if table exist in current connection?

Tags: jdbc, connection, metadata

jdbc: is there a way to check if a table exist in current connection?

```
connection.getMetaData().getTables(catalog, schema, table, ...)
```

It requires schema and catelog.

Comment: Exactly what is your question, because you can find that with `DatabaseMetaData.getTables`. Doesn't it work for you? What did you try? Did you actually read the javadoc?

Comment: For a method with connection parameter only without knowing schema and catalog, is there way to get a table info? connection is created using jdbc url.

Comment: Please read the documentation, passing null will return for all catalogs and schemas

Comment: get the table in the schema associated with current connection only, not all schemas.

Comment: Then get the current catalog and schema from the Connection object.

Comment: thanks. but jdbc connection on android does not have connection.getSchema().